# How to join a table to itself using rank multiple times?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I apologize if there is an existing solution, I tried searching quite a bit but couldnt find much.

Here's what I am trying to do:

I have a table that resembles the first image. I want it to look like the second image. Basically every time `rnk_address = 1`, I want that row's `order_date` to be moved into a separate column for that associated `user_id`.

I'm ultimately trying to calculate the average difference in `order_date` between all `rnk_address = 1`, by `user_id`.

I added a `user_counter` column using rank because I imagine I will need to do some time of join where i do `user_rank = user_rank + 1`? But not sure....

**Original table:**

[image]

**End result:**

[image]

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or, even worse, links to images.)

Comment: Format your question with text instead of images, very difficult to interpret

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select user_id, first_name,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then order_date end) as order_date_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then order_date end) as order_date_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then order_date end) as order_date_3
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id order by order_date) as seqnum
      from t
      where rnk_address = 1
     ) t
group by user_id, first_name;
```

Comment: just to be clear, the "Seqnum" partition you did - isnt that the same thing as my user_counter column? also, why are we doing max() function for order_date_1, etc? thank you for teh help

Comment: @jc315 . . . No, `seqnum` is not the same as the `user_counter` column; it is calculated after filtering.  The `max()` is for gathering the values into a single row.